# Why "puts" output is indented in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, puts

Given the following Ruby program:

```
def getch
  begin
    system("stty raw -echo")
    ch = STDIN.getc
    puts "[#{ch}]"
    ch
  ensure
    system("stty -raw echo")
  end
end

print "Press a key: "
getch
puts "Have a nice day!"
```

and the following run:

```
$ ruby a.rb 
Press a key: [t]
              Have a nice day!
```

Why "Have a nice day!" is indented? Why the output is not like that:

```
$ ruby a.rb 
Press a key: [t]
Have a nice day!
```

?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, adding `opost` should fix it. Change you third line to look like this:

```
system("stty raw opost -echo")
```

I hope this is the answer you are looking for.